# LDAP extensible match filter LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

When I run the following I end up with a good list of results:

```
base = 'OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=myserver,DC=com'
criteria = 'CN=My Example'
attributes = ['member', 'groupType', 'description', 'memberOf']

result = connection.search_ext_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes, sizelimit=0)
```

However I can't seem to find anything that helps me when using an LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN.

```
base = 'OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=myserver,DC=com'
criteria = '1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MatchedRuleChainExample'
attributes = ['member', 'groupType', 'description', 'memberOf']

result = connection.search_ext_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes, sizelimit=0)
```

The above always returns blank. Can anyone help me grasp this? I feel completely lost on how to get through the subgroups in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This criteria syntax `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MatchedRuleChainExample` is wrong.

The [string representation of an LDAP extensible match filter](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) must be comprised of the following components in order :

> - An opening parenthesis
> - The name of the attribute type, or an empty string if none was provided
> - The string ":dn" if the dnAttributes flag is set, or an empty string if not
> - If a matching rule ID is available, then a string comprised of a colon followed by that OID, or an empty string if there is no matching
>     rule ID
> - The string ":="
> - The string representation of the assertion value
> - A closing parenthesis

To sum it up, it should look like :

```
([<attr>][:dn][:<OID>]:=<assertion>)

# In your case, fixing the attribute position :
(cn:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=MatchedRuleChainExample)
```

But there is another issue here : `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` only works when used with Distinguished Names (DN) type attributes (like `member` or  `memberOf` that are commonly used with extensible match filter), but `cn` is not, so it can't work.

To grab all `Security Groups` member of `CN=My Example`, including nested groups, use the `memberOf` attribute with extensible match and apply it to the group's *dn*.

```
# Fixing the attribute type and assertion value :
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=<groupDN>)
```

Also, you need to filter `objectClass` to match only group entries (group members could also be users or machines). So in the end, the filter criteria should look like :

```
(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=My Example,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=myserver,DC=com))
```

cf. [Active Directory Group Related Searches](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches)

*Note that `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` is available only on Domain Controllers with Windows Server 2003 R2 (or above).*

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you have any knowledge on how search_ext_s formats the query? I have searched the official docs but can't seem to figure it out in order to modify my python call to search through this correctly.

Comment: The simplest would be to check the ldap logs to see how the final query looks like while tweaking the function parameters from a terminal.

Comment: The simplest would be to check the ldap logs to see how the final query looks like while tweaking the function parameters from a terminal. Also in your code you can try to set `criteria = '(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=My Example,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=myserver,DC=com))'`, and also you may want to request all attributes, `attributes = ['*']` then eventually pick only those you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been a huge help!